# There is any way for limit the size of a string in a POJO and throw a specific exception if exceds the limit?

Tags: java

I need a fast solution to limit an attribute for have a specific limit and if it exceds the limit throw a custom exception, something like an annotation, for specify the limit and exception to be throwed. there is any like this in java 8 ?

Example:

```
@Size(max=20, ex=CustomEx, msg= "Exced the limit")
private String myAttribute;
```

Comment: Standard way would be to do this with a setter that ran this test.  Java does not do this for you (but see this: [Java Setters and Getters](/questions/1907312)).  `public void setMyAttribute(String value) { if (null != value && value.length() > 20) ...`

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to put your validation code in a setter:

```
public void setMyAttribute(String value) throws CustomEx {
    if (value != null && value.length() > 20) {
        throw new CustomEx("Exceeded the limit");
    }

    myAttribute = value;
}
```

**Edit**: Validation when using a constructor:

```
public MyClass(String value) throws CustomEx {  // the constructor
    setMyAttribute(value);
}
```

Comment: and if the object was created from a constructor with all args ?

Comment: Then your constructor can call the internal setter methods to have the validation performed.

Comment: Would actually be an option to make your Pojo immutable and do everything in the constructor - wouldn't need the setter methods at all.